# dns reverse proxy for resolving txt records

Tags: proxy, reverse-dns

Is this possible if multiple urls are pointing as CNAME to a same URL and should resolve different TXT records based on the input url eg:

```
sample.somedomain.com -> mydomain.example.com -> TXT record for sample.somedomain.com
test.anotherdomain.com -> mydomain.example.com -> TXT record for test.anotherdomain.com
```

can someone tell if this is possible by running a proxy dns server on mydomain.example.com if so how we can do it is there any docs for it?

i have tried running proxy dns server but not able to achieve it

Comment: In general answer is NO, when `mydomain.example.com` is queried by a DNS resolver there's no (reliable) way (and possibly no way at all) to determine if that DNS record was queried directly, or if that query was made following a CNAME let alone what CNAME pointed to `mydomain.example.com`  (I don't think DNS has anything like the HTTP Referrer header.)

Comment: I think DNS response policy zone (RPZ) syntax also doesn't allows for a dynamic construction *"if the response is a CNAME to `mydomain.example.com` change the response to something QNAME specific" .  RPZ syntax is more like "if QNAME is "sample.somedomain.com "  then respond with predefined "TXT record for sample.somedomain.com"